# Vlc media player full screen black rectangle

Tags: display, monitor

Whenever I change to full screen I see a small black shape of a rectangle for a split second.
Plz help, I am new to UBUNTU 20.04
I use acer aspire e5 and I completely erased windows
I only have Ubuntu 20.04
I have amd Radeon graphics card of 2gb and 4gb ram.
The processor is amd a8

Comment: Possibly a graphics driver problem - if you could [edit] and add hardware details that might make this answerable. Also update with the latest status since in a comment on the answer you said that you removed VLC (how?) - are you still having problems with multiple option indicators for VLC after that?

Comment: Yes, the three dot indicator regarding vlc has vanished

Answer (score -2):

@LE VAN DEES
rather uninstall and reinstall VLC.

1: **unistall**

1. Method 1 - Open Terminal and type: `sudo apt-get remove vlc`
2. Method 2 - Open Ubuntu software - ***Install*** applications tab - find and remove VLC

2: **reinstall**

1. Method 1: Launch Terminal and type - `sudo snap install VLC`
2. Method 2: Open your browser and type in the URL   ***apt://vlc*** and follow instructions

*Remember to update and upgrade your system before and after:*

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I removed vlc today. I installed Kodi media player. Still the issue didn't resolve. A rectangular thing flashes for a second